# Cannot find in ckeditor docs a full list of supported elements & attributes, which I could use with writer.createElement() method

Tags: ckeditor5

I want to add some elements to model. I see, that there is a **writer.createElement()** method https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html, but cannot find which element names are supported, and with which attributes.